ASP.NET MVC area issue on IIS 10
I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application (on .NET 4.8), and I have recently added an area to the application (area is registered and the route is mapped).
When I deployed the app to IIS, it works as expected on the local server, but when I try to access the area via the domain name, I get redirected to the default app page and there seems no way to access the newly added area.
During my research, I came across URL Rewriting rules; I tried everything I found but no use

Check your web.config file to ensure that there are no conflicting settings or URL rewriting rules that might be causing unexpected redirections.

@YurongDai, checked and all is good, I know it may has nothing to do with it, but could the HTTP protocol be the issue, because when I run the application on the hosting machine, it works...

You can get better answers if you provide with more details - now it only allows for guessing. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example? See How to Ask for further guidance.

I saw you posted the same question on the Microsoft Q&A platform, case link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1663391/asp-net-mvc-area-issue-on-iis-10. I will follow up on the Q&A.

Yes I did, I found the reason behind it as I was using Cookies (without user consent) to store data which caused the issue, as a solution, I moved the data to Session variables and now all is good, thanks.
